# Split text into words & numbers with unicode support (preg_split)

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to split (with preg_split) a text with a lot of foreign chars and digits into words and numbers with length >= 2 and without ponctuation.
Now I have this code but it only split into words without taking account digits and length >= 2 for all.
How can I do please?

```
$text = 'abc 文 字化け, efg Yukarda mavi gök, asağıda yağız yer yaratıldıkta; (1998 m. siejės 7 d.). Ton pate dėina bandomkojė бойынша бірінші орында тұр (79.65 %), айына 41';
$splitted = preg_split('#\P{L}+#u', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Expected result should be : `array('abc', '字化け', 'efg', 'Yukarda', 'mavi', 'gök', 'asağıda', 'yağız', 'yer', 'yaratıldıkta', '1998', 'siejės', 'Ton', 'pate', 'dėina', 'bandomkojė', 'бойынша', 'бірінші', 'орында', 'тұр', '79.65', 'айына', '41');`

NB : already tried with these docs [link1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) & [link2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) but i can't get it works :-/

Comment: What's the actual result that you're getting?

Comment: For now result is : Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => 文
    [2] => 字化け
    [3] => efg
    [4] => Yukarda
    [5] => mavi
    [6] => gök
    [7] => asağıda
    [8] => yağız
    [9] => yer
    [10] => yaratıldıkta
    [11] => m
    [12] => siejės
    [13] => d
    [14] => Ton
    [15] => pate
    [16] => dėina
    [17] => bandomkojė
    [18] => бойынша
    [19] => бірінші
    [20] => орында
    [21] => тұр
    [22] => айына
)

Comment: Do you mean that you _don't_ want it to match on any word that contains punctuation (i.e. '79.65' is not matched) or would you want it to match on '79' and '65' ?

Comment: Nope I want getting float, so should match 79.65, just don't want single isolated punctuation chars..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *preg_match_all* instead, then you can check the length condition (that is hard to do with preg_split, but not impossible):

```
$text = 'abc 文 字化け, efg Yukarda mavi gök, asağıda yağız yer yaratıldıkta; (1998 m. siejės 7 d.). Ton pate dėina bandomkojė бойынша бірінші орында тұр (79.65 %), айына 41';
preg_match_all('~\p{L}{2,}+|\d{2,}+(?>\.\d++)?|\d\.\d++~u',$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

explanation:

```
   p{L}{2,}+          # letter 2 or more times
|                  # OR
   \d{2,}+            # digit 2 or more times
   (?>\.\d++)?        # can be a decimal number
|                  # OR
   \d\.\d++           # single digit MUST be followed by at least a decimal 
                      # (length constraint)
```

Comment: Hum, seems preg_split is more efficient than preg_match_all, that's why I wanted use it (real $text is really huge...).
And if we forget length condition is this possible? How could I combine [\P{N}]+ and [\P{L}]+ ?? Yes i'm totally noob with regex :-/

Comment: @Albertine: You can compose a character class like this `[^\p{N}\p{L}]` but the problem of decimal number stay.

Comment: @Albertine: IMO, the best answer is from dev-nul-dweiller, you can improve it like this: `#\d++\.\d++|[^\W_]{2,}+#u`

Comment: Ok, I will use preg_match_all, it's simpler. Thank you very much for your help man !
Sorry I can't vote for your answer because don't have enough reputation :-/

Answer (score 1):

With a little hack to match digits separated by dot before matching only digits as part of the word:

```
preg_match_all("#(?:\d+\.\d+|\w{2,})#u", $text, $matches);
$splitted = $matches[0];
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/X7Ln1V

Answer (score 0):

Splitting CJK into "words" is kind of meaningless.  Each character is a word.  If you use whitespace the you split into phrases.

So it depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.  If you're indexing text, then you need to consider bigrams and/or CJK idioms.

Comment: Yes this is for indexing text, so I will take a look about these notions. Thank you !